# Running QField without a Google account

Tags: android, qfield

I'd like to give QField a try but I can not install it from Google Play Store. I do not want to create a Google account for privacy concerns.

Is there a possibility to install QField without using Play Store and a Google account, for example by using F-Droid?

Answer (score 4):

[All releases can be downloaded directly from the github page](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases), as [stated in the documentation](https://www.qfield.org/docs/installation-guide/index.html). All .apk packages there are signed.

If someone wants to make the effort of uploading it to F-Droid and keeping it up to date, that will be very welcome. If you want to dig into this best contact the [user list](http://lists.qfield.org/listinfo.cgi/users-qfield.org) or the [github issue page](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues) to coordinate or for specific questions.